# Expand & collapse HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Disclaimer: I am a HTML, javascript and CSS novice.

What I am trying to do is have an expandable/collapsible HTML table as shown below.  Clicking on "Values 1" should display "Category 1" (there are other categories but to minimise the code I have only displayed 1 category).  Then clicking on "Category 1" will display further SubValues.  The problem is when clicking on "Values 1" it only hides "Category 1" while still displaying the SubValues.  Any ideas how I can easily change this with minimal code changes so that clicking on Values 1 hides both Category 1 and the SubValues.  Note that there are also more Categories and SubValues so would also need them hidden.

Ideally, clicking "Values 1" should hide all Categories and SubValues, while clicking it again should restore the Categories and SubValues to whatever state they were, either hidden or visible.

Hopefully this makes sense.  Thanks in advance

Collapsed:

[image: Collapsed version]

Expanded (wrong):

[image: Expanded version]

Fully expanded:
[image]

```js
< script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="toggle"]').change(function() {
      $(this).parents().next('.hide').toggle();
    });
  });

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".expandFRED").click(function() {
      $(".expandSUB1").toggle();
    });
    $(".expandVALS").click(function() {
      $(".expandCAT1").toggle();
    });
  }) <
  /script>
```

```css
.label tr td label {
  display: block;
}

[data-toggle='toggle'] {
  display: none;
}

.expandSUB1 {
  display: none;
}

. {
  display: none;
}

.expandCAT1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <table class='imagetable' align='center'>
    <caption><b></b></caption>
    <tbody class="labels">
      <tr>
        <td class='expandFRED' colspan='7'>Values 1 (click here to expand/collapse)
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="hide">
      <tr>
        <td class='expandSUB1 expandVALS'>Category 1 (click here to expand/collapse)
        </td>
        <td class='expandSUB1'></td>
        <td class='expandSUB1' align='right'>$461.11
        </td>
        <td class='expandSUB1'></td>
        <td class='expandSUB1' align='right'>$428.33</td>
        <td class='expandSUB1' align='right'>-7.11%
        </td>
        <td class='expandSUB1' align='right'>$-32.78</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='expandCAT1'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SubValue 1</td>
        <td class='expandCAT1' align='right'>0.405582</td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
        <td class='expandCAT1' align='right'>0.405582</td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='expandCAT1'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SubValue 2</td>
        <td class='expandCAT1' align='right'>1</td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
        <td class='expandCAT1' align='right'>1</td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='expandCAT1'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SubValue 3</td>
        <td class='expandCAT1' align='right'>1.392379</td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
        <td class='expandCAT1' align='right'>1.407569</td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try searching on the website w3schools.com - lots of helpful html info there

Comment: A few things, I would suggest you beautify your code, because it's extremely hard for everyone to read. You're going to want to start using tabs or spaces to clean it up, alot of the time you'll spot the issue by just using proper syntax styling.

Comment: @reecec:  Check the answer given below.

Comment: @reecec: Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52699171/1516616) is what you want

Comment: Thank you Ahsan that is brilliant.  Thank you for cleaning it up and getting it working it was a huge help.  Also thanks to NikhilKinkar for cleaning up my code that is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED:**

Replace with below code:

```
$(".expandFRED").click(function() {
  $('.hide').toggle();  
});
$(".expandVALS").click(function() {
  $(".expandCAT1").toggle();
});
```

**CSS Change**:

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

and remove below:

```
.expandSUB1 {
   display: none;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".expandFRED").click(function() {
      $('.hide').toggle();  
    });
    $(".expandVALS").click(function() {
      $(".expandCAT1").toggle();
    });
  })
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.expandCAT1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <table class='imagetable table' align='center'>
    <caption><b></b></caption>
    <tbody class="labels">
      <tr>
        <td class='expandFRED' colspan='7'>Values 1 (click here to expand/collapse)
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="hide">
      <tr>
        <td class='expandSUB1 expandVALS'>Category 1 (click here to expand/collapse)
        </td>
        <td class='expandSUB1'></td>
        <td class='expandSUB1' align='right'>$461.11
        </td>
        <td class='expandSUB1'></td>
        <td class='expandSUB1' align='right'>$428.33</td>
        <td class='expandSUB1' align='right'>-7.11%
        </td>
        <td class='expandSUB1' align='right'>$-32.78</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='expandCAT1'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SubValue 1</td>
        <td class='expandCAT1' align='right'>0.405582</td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
        <td class='expandCAT1' align='right'>0.405582</td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='expandCAT1'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SubValue 2</td>
        <td class='expandCAT1' align='right'>1</td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
        <td class='expandCAT1' align='right'>1</td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='expandCAT1'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SubValue 3</td>
        <td class='expandCAT1' align='right'>1.392379</td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
        <td class='expandCAT1' align='right'>1.407569</td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
        <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks this is the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Hi in my little knowledge you should toggle the hide class in expandFRED
class click event for toggle the whole table below is the total code

Please you apply your css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="toggle"]').change(function() {
    $(this).parents().next('.hide').toggle();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".expandFRED").click(function() {
    $(".expandSUB1").toggle();
  });
  $(".expandVALS").click(function() {
    $(".expandCAT1").toggle();
  });
  $(".expandFRED").click(function() {
    $(".hide").toggle();
  });
})
```

```css
.imagetable {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.label tr td label {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

[data-toggle='toggle'] {
  display: block;
}


/*.expandSUB1 {
            display: block;
        }

        .expandFRED {
            display: block;
        }

            .expandCAT1 {
                display: block;
            }*/
```

```html
<table class='imagetable' align='center'>
  <caption><b></b></caption>
  <tbody class="labels">
    <tr>
      <td class='expandFRED' colspan='7'>
        Values 1 (click here to expand/collapse)
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="hide">
    <tr>
      <td class='expandSUB1 expandVALS'>
        Category 1 (click here to expand/collapse)
      </td>
      <td class='expandSUB1'></td>
      <td class='expandSUB1' align='right'>
        $461.11
      </td>
      <td class='expandSUB1'></td>
      <td class='expandSUB1' align='right'>$428.33</td>
      <td class='expandSUB1' align='right'>
        -7.11%
      </td>
      <td class='expandSUB1' align='right'>$-32.78</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='expandCAT1'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SubValue 1</td>
      <td class='expandCAT1' align='right'>0.405582</td>
      <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
      <td class='expandCAT1' align='right'>0.405582</td>
      <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
      <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
      <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='expandCAT1'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SubValue 2</td>
      <td class='expandCAT1' align='right'>1</td>
      <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
      <td class='expandCAT1' align='right'>1</td>
      <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
      <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
      <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='expandCAT1'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SubValue 3</td>
      <td class='expandCAT1' align='right'>1.392379</td>
      <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
      <td class='expandCAT1' align='right'>1.407569</td>
      <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
      <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
      <td class='expandCAT1'></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response LDS I think your answer was quite good and seemed to work pretty well, but have marked the other reply as the correct one as I can only put 1 correct answer.  Appreciate your time on this one